# how to assign a value to textbox which is outside of the updatePanel

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax

i am having a Page.in that page button inside a UpdatePanel.when a user click on the button.
i need to assign a value to textbox which is outside of the updatepanel.

how to achieve this ? any suggestion it will be there ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also place the TextBox in a Update panel, leave the button out of the update panel and set a trigger that will cause the button to do a Async postback like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTextBox" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="tbTitle" runat="server" />
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
     </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And then add a button event that will change the text of the text box.

Or if you don't want to add the text box in a Update Panel you can register a startup script to set the text of the textBox something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setTextBoxText", "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#"+tbTitle.ClientId+"').val('submit button has been clicked');</script>", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the TextBox in a updatepanel with a trigger to the button here's a example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Btn1" runat="server />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Btn1" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And on the Button Click, you can change the value of txtBox1 and call upd2.Update()

Answer (score 0):

IIRC You would need to call `.Update()` on the additional controls (perhaps placing them in a second `UpdatePanel` and calling `.Update()` on *that*). [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx) for an example.

Comment: ... and add an async trigger on the panel containing the textbox, so that clicking on the button will update the text.